# Three JS color, metalness, lights, shaders are not working on my mobile

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js, webgl

This is my code with Three.js. Here I've written a simple code for a red colored, point light and a textured torus with a simple animation. But I got only a black colored torus rotating.

The things written in this code doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ThreeJS Starter</title>
<style>
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #242424;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="module">

   import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
   import { MeshStandardMaterial } from '../src/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.js';


//scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1000 );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
          alpha : true
        });
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(12,3,140,100);
        
        const texture = new  THREE.TextureLoader().load('../examples/textures/golf.jpg');

    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
  light.position.set(2,3,4);
  scene.add(light);

        const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
          color: 0xff0000,
          roughness: 0.5,
          metalness: 0.75
        });
        
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 60;

        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };

        animate();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle and modified your code in order to work:
https://jsfiddle.net/hrm3ab97/show

1. Since I used jsfiddle, I provided a full external path for three.js module. That made the torus appear.
2. In case your phone does not support the default WebGL 2, I changed it to WebGL 1, just remove "1" from 'WebGl1Renderer' to see if it still works.
3. I moved the light further in order to fully light the torus -unless you wanted to light just its inner ring.
4. The texture code wasn't complete, so I modified the method that loads the texture and applies the map in order to work -I picked a random texture from three.js examples website as they don't limit cross-origin usage.
   If you remove the 'map' from the material you'll see the simple red
   material color.
5. remove 'show' from the jsfiddle link to disable fullscreen and see the code. There is a bug in the stackoverflow editor that prevents the full HTML code to appear, so I omitted it here.

   ```
       import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';


       //scene
       const scene = new THREE.Scene();
       const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1000 );

       const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
         alpha : true
       });
       renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
       document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

       const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(12,3,140,100);

       const map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg' );
               map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

       const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({  
         roughness: 0.5,
         metalness: 0.75,
         map: map, 

       });

       const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
       light.position.set(20,30,40);
       scene.add(light);

       const torus = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
       scene.add( torus );

       camera.position.z = 40;

       const animate = function () {
           requestAnimationFrame( animate );

           torus.rotation.x += 0.01;
           torus.rotation.y += 0.01;

           renderer.render( scene, camera );
       };

       animate();
   ```